# Why Angular 2+ - Dist folder contains files with unique id

Tags: angular

I have a few queries in Angular application. Please help me to understand.

1. why ng build generate files with unique id. for example "main-es5.**82cxxxxxxxxxxxx1e58**.js"
2. If we change code in my component.ts/Html file, Is it sufficient to move only main-es5.xxxxxxx.js & main.es2015.xxxxxxxxx.js file to the production server to reflect the changes OR Do we have to move the complete dist folder?

Answer (score 0):

It's used to prevent browser JS caching between releases.

You will also need to modify `index.html` with the corresponding urls.

I would advise to let Angular do what it does best and use the output as is to prevent unexpected results on production.

Comment: Regarding Prevent cache, why does each time I deploy a new release, user has to clean the entire browser cache to see the UI effects? Recently I used to deploy using --output-hashing=all